# how can I change the proxy settings through macOS Terminal?

Tags: macbook-pro

In my macOS Terminal, I`m trying to install software using brew install ****, so every time its connecting office proxy new giving timeout error. if  I`m checking the proxy settings everything is clear and working internet using chrome and safari. can please resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to change the proxy settings for macOS from the command line, then use these commands for Web (HTTP/HTTPS) proxy

```
networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-fi" 127.0.0.1 8080
networksetup -setwebproxystate "Wi-fi" on
networksetup -getwebproxy "Wi-Fi"
```

For SOCKS proxy

```
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy wi-fi localhost 1080
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate "Wi-Fi" on
networksetup -getsocksfirewallproxystate "Wi-Fi"
```

## Homebrew with SOCKS proxy

I think what you are trying to achieve is to use your office's proxy server for Homebrew to work. Try these commands

```
http_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:1080 brew install foo
http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 brew install foo
ALL_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:1080 brew install foo
```

## Proxychains

If that does not work, use `proxychains` with Homebrew.

```
brew install proxychains-ng
```

Assuming you can connect to another network that can run brew. Otherwise use your browser to manually download and install proxychains-ng https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng

Then create a config file at `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf`

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns 
remote_dns_subnet 224
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
quiet_mode

[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080
```

Append `proxychains` in front of your `brew` command

```
proxychains brew install foo
```